# Does a phasor of composite sinusoid give information?

Tags: ac, phasor, sinusoidal

I have a circuit with multiple supplies and each power supply has a different frequency. Would adding the rectangular form of the output give useful information about the composite sinusoid waveform?

For example 3 power supplies,

1,DC voltage output = -1 V

2,AC voltage output = 2.34cos(5t-30.78) V

3,AC voltage output = 2.29cos(2t-77.8) V

Sum = -1 + 2.34cos(5t-30.78) + 2.29cos(2t-77.8)

Can they be further simplified further into a single phasor or rectangular complex number?

Comment: a phasor ... is a complex number representing a sinusoidal function whose amplitude, angular frequency, and initial phase are time-invariant. Amplitude, frequency, and phase in this definition are singular nouns, but your *Sum* function has three amplitudes, three frequencies and two phases. So, add two and two to come to a conclusion. As for a 'rectangular complex number', the phasor 'is related a more general concept called analytic representation, which decomposes a sinusoid into the product of a complex constant and a factor depending on time and frequency'.

Comment: Citations are from Wikipedia, but any reliable source where you may have read about phasors (textbook, course notes) should be giving you these definitions and explanations. If you only heard of phasors in class, read any reliable textbook, course notes on this subject. It is a must!

Comment: If the circuit is linear, you can use superposition.